# h264_qsv leads to memory leak

Tags: mlt

I use h264_qsv encoder to export a video.
The mlt xml :

```
<consumer mlt_service="avformat" target="10.mp4" strict="experimental" vn="0" vcodec="h264_qsv" width="1920" height="800" frame_rate_num="50.000000" frame_rate_den="1" vb="8000k" cbr="1" vbufsize="12288000" minrate="8000k" maxrate="8000k" acodec="aac" channels="1" ar="44100" ab="192k" preset="fast" profile="main" level="3.0" bf="0" thread="0" real_time="-1" sc_threshold="0" g="125" f="mp4" preview_off="1"/>
```

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try elaborating on "none seem to work". What happens with the xml in the question? Is there an error message? (if yes, what is it?) Is the output wrong?

Comment: More information needed. The title says memory leak. But the description does not give evidence of a leak. How do you know that it does not work? Is a file created? If so, what properties does it have in mediainfo or VLC metadata?